# In Objective-C, return something that has to wait before its done

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

Consider following code involving `SpecialRequest`, which has member `result` that is not populated right away:

```
- (NSArray *)getXboxSizedArray {
   SpecialRequest *request = [SpecialRequest request];
   request.someParam = 11; //and so forth...
   [request start];
}
```

And say there is a callback for `requestFinished`:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(SpecialRequest *)request {
   //hooray!
}
```

I want to return the value of `request.result`, but of course only after the request has completed (which I would know from `-(void)requestFinished`. How do I do this?

Edit: Note that I have tried putting a return statement inside a block, and failed miserably.

Edit 1: Here is an example of bad and non working code if you are interested:

```
- (NSString *)getAllDogFoodBrand {
    __unsafe_unretained __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"some_url"]];
    request.delegate = self;
    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        [self.delegate objectControllerDidFinishRequestWithStatus:request.responseStatusMessage];
        //return request.responseString; <-- this line makes compiler :(
    }];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}
```

Comment: You could use a notification.

Comment: How would I use a notification?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to create a wrapper class for your request with a method that accepts a block parameter. The block parameter could be stored in an instance variable (generally a `copy` property) and after the request has finished the completion block stored in the instance variable can be called from the `-requestFinished:` callback method. This is in my opinion a neater approach compared to using delegates.

Comment: How would the compiler know that the function returns something? Can it evaluate what happens with blocks?

Comment: By wrapping the SpecialRequest object in a class, the wrapper class will contain the -requestFinished: callback. Within this callback you just call the block that was supplied on start of the async method. So the compiler doesn't really have to know anything. I hope this is clear, else I might have to upload some sort of example.

Comment: Let's say the wrapper class (SpecialRequestWrapper) contains one method: `-requestWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(void))block`. The wrapper class also handles the `-requestFinished:` callback. Within the `-requestWithCompletionBlock:` method you store the block parameter in a property. The block stored in the property is called again in the delegate method `-requestFinished:`.

Comment: just saw your latest comment... please ignore Why would this help though? In this case, `SpecialRequest` is `ASIHTTPRequest`, and this is already a class that has the `requestFinished` callback method. In the code above, I've attempted to use blocks but fail because it seems you cannot put a return statement in a block...

Comment: In that case you might have to consider a different approach. Perhaps it's a better idea to refactor your `-getXboxSizedArray` method to look like this: `- (void)getXboxSizedArray:(void (^)(NSArray *array)completionBlock` and just use this block to return the response to the caller.

Comment: Ok, so in that case, the caller would need to provide that completion block... please forgive me if I am being thick.

Comment: Yes, and that seems a much cleaner approach to me. Your caller code will probably look somewhat like this: `[SomeClass getXboxSizedArray:^ (NSArray *array) { self.results = array; }];`

Comment: What about the fact that the Caller is not the delegate, and the delegator needs to access the delegate?

Comment: To be more clear, this is not a situation where it is Caller (Delegate) -> Delegator. In this situation, I have ViewController (Delegate) CALLS Model Class Method CALLS Model Controller Instance Method (Delegator)

Comment: It's kind of hard to explain, but I feel you're using the ASIHTTPRequest library in the wrong way, especially with regards to blocks which you seem to link to delegate methods. This feeling is based on my experience with AFNetworking. But I'd need to see much more code with regards to write down an alternative implementation.

Comment: You are probably right... This is a lot of maneuvering. Basically my goal is to have the `ViewController` as decoupled from web service stuff as possible. I would like to use a single line in the `ViewController`, like `self.models = [Model allModels]` and have `+ (NSArray *)allModels` call the `ModelController -(NSArray *)getModels`. With synchronous requests, this is very straightforward, but of course most requests should be asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for that purposes combination of `delegate` and `protocol`.
For example, here you could find a small tutorial: [The Basics of Protocols and Delegates](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html)

Also you could use KVC with KVO. Check here about that approaches here: [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

Comment: How do I use callbacks to do implement this, though? In my actual controller (not its delegate), I need a return statement in the function that is used to get the stuff.. And yet with delegation it seems that I need to put the return statement somehow in the actual callback method, which is not possible.

Comment: 1. Save delegator. 2. Call `getXboxSizedArray`. 3. After `requestFinished:` fired call delegators method.

Comment: What do you mean by "save delegator?"

Comment: Decline `property` that will store reference to `delegator`.